# How to get total size of the folder in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I want to know the total size of the folder created in Palantir Foundry. The folder may have N number of repositories , N number of datasets, any other data. I should get total size of the selected folder. Anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer exactly what you asked, but you could use the Resource Management app to create a Usage Account that contains the projects that you're interested in tracking. In doing so you would also get other metrics that you might be interested in, like Batch Compute and Interactive Compute. You would also get information about how those metrics have been changing over time.